# XGZP6847A Pressure Sensor Modul

Tags: arduino

hey guys I'm trying to measure the pressure of a vacuum pump using the XGZP6847A pressure sensor I need the pressure to be around -95kpa [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5ps1.png): https://www.micros.com.pl/mediaserver/CZ_XGZP6847a010kpg_0001.pdf
but the voltage that is supposed to make that happen is 0,475 ( modele 100KPGn) and while I was reading the datasheet [image: 1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5ps1.png]

I didn't understand the yellow line can someone explain to me how I'm supposed to reverse the output with the pressure line

Comment: Sadly that datasheet suffers from chinglish grammar. The best I can guess is that they can make a special part  calibration with the scale reversed.

Answer (score 1):

The statement you highlighted in yellow is apparently an option to select when ordering the part from the manufacturer.

If you look at how the document you refer to uses the term *calibrate* in the other two places in the document, the calibration appears to be done by the OEM during the manufacturing process.  Calibration of the component doesn't appear to be an option after manufacturing.  Thus, further calibration would need to be in the circuitry external to the component.

**Figure 1**. First occurrence of Calibrate

[image]

**Figure 2**.  Second occurrence of Calibrate

[image]

Comment: i need like to reverse the voltage like when the output is 4,5v i need the pressure to be -100kpa there is a way to do that???

Comment: An inverting amplifier with the right DC offset would do that for you. But it would usually be easier to invert in software if you're reading this with an ADC.

Comment: u talking about the equation of y=xm+b